# showing a div within a parent element by traversing siblings

Tags: jquery, siblings

In my WordPress site. I have two "Learn More" links on my homepage. When either one is clicked I would like them to revile the corresponding paragraph above and change the "Learn More" to "Close". Currently clicking either button reveals both.

```
.hide-mobile {
    display: none;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".learnMore").on("click", function(e) {
        var $a = $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
        $a.text(function(i, t) {
            return t === 'Learn More' ? 'Close' : 'Learn More';
        });
        $( "p" ).siblings( ".reveal" ).slideToggle(500);
    });
});

<div class="box-one box">
<h2>Header One</h2>
<p class="hide-mobile reveal">Etiam ut vehicula velit. Cras ut ipsum id tortor ultrices iaculis. Donec sodales ultricies urna vitae porta.</p>
<a class="button" href="/link-url/">Button One</a>
<a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="box-two box">
<h2>Header Two</h2>
<p class="hide-mobile reveal">Morbi et varius elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
<a class="button" href="/link-url-two/">Button Two</a>
<a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why starting to lookup from the `<p>` elements?

```
$( "p" ).siblings( ".reveal" ).slideToggle(500);
```

When the `.reveal` element also is the `p` you wish to target?
`this` is what you need!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".learnMore").on("click", function(e) {
    var $a = $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
    $a.text(function(i, t) {
      return t === 'Learn More' ? 'Close' : 'Learn More';
    });
    $( this ).siblings( ".reveal" ).slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-mobile {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-one box">
  <h2>Header One</h2>
  <p class="hide-mobile reveal">Etiam ut vehicula velit. Cras ut ipsum id tortor ultrices iaculis. Donec sodales ultricies urna vitae porta.</p>
  <a class="button" href="/link-url/">Button One</a>
  <a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="box-two box">
  <h2>Header Two</h2>
  <p class="hide-mobile reveal">Morbi et varius elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
  <a class="button" href="/link-url-two/">Button Two</a>
  <a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.